# Ubuntu for Lenovo ThinkPad T60

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad

Can you recommend a most stable and compatible but fast Ubuntu version for Lenovo T60 2008-jl6 with 1 GB RAM ? and where can I find all the other compatible driver for finger print, touch pad, etc ?

Where can I find the setup CD for your recommended version ?

Answer (score 0):

You could install Ubuntu inst 12.04 or 13.04.  But I recommend that you install Xubuntu 13.04.

> Xubuntu is an elegant and easy-to-use operating system. Xubuntu comes
>   with Xfce, which is a stable, light and configurable desktop
>   environment.
>
> Xubuntu is perfect for those who want the most out of their desktops,
>   laptops and netbooks with a modern look and enough features for
>   efficient, daily usage. It works well on older hardware too.<sup>[Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/)</sup>

You can download the DVD [Here](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/)  Once downloaded you can burn the ISO to DVD, and boot from it, or create a bootable USB flash drive.  To burn the DVD you can use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/), and for the USB you can use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).